# Nodejs: Expecting a function in instanceof check but got undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Getting this odd error when using node-webkit, here is a complete example which can recreate it:

index.js:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');

(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');    
       this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
    }
  });
  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
 <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

The stack trace:

```
TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got undefined
at _.extend.setElement     (C:\SVN\mapthing\branches\mapthing_js\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1046:45)
at _.extend._ensureElement (C:\SVN\mapthing\branches\mapthing_js\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1108:14)
at Backbone.View (C:\SVN\mapthing\branches\mapthing_js\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1000:10)
at new child (C:\SVN\mapthing\branches\mapthing_js\node_modules\backbone\backbone.js:1566:41)
at file:///C:/SVN/mapthing/branches/mapthing_js/js/index.js:18:18
at file:///C:/SVN/mapthing/branches/mapthing_js/js/index.js:19:3
```

Having trouble seeing where my problem is?

Most solutions seem to point to having to require `jquery` first, but I have done this...

I'm a relative n00b so I'm expecting ive done something very daft...

Comment: I take it you aren't calling `instanceof`? It would be helpful to see the code that is causing the issue. If it's happening in the background, can you post your stack trace?

Comment: @RobM. I have edited to provide a complete, minimal example that gives the same behaviour, along with the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, so be warned of that, but the error is coming from this method in the backbone lib (`node_modules/backbone/backbone.js:1046` from your stacktrace):

```
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
  if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
  this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
  this.el = this.$el[0];
  if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
},
```

Most likely you can circumvent this error by explicitly setting jQuery on Backbone, like this:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = jQuery;
```

That is a totally untested guess, but it should work.